# Wake Mac mini running Windows 7 using Apple remote

Tags: windows-7, sleep, mac-mini, wake-up, apple-remote

I have just installed Windows 7 Pro 32 bit to a 2010 Mac mini (using Bootcamp). I also have the current (2nd gen) Apple Remote.

How can I wake the machine from sleep under Windows 7 with the remote? I tried all the buttons on the remote but no luck.

Under OS X I can wake it up with the remote without problems

**Update**:

- just wanted to make clear that otherwise the remote is functional under Windows - I can control VLC player, for example.
- The `Human Interface Device Access` service was already started. I changed the Startup type from `Manual` to `Automatic`, also tried stopping/starting the service manually - all this while rebooting between changes. Unfortunately it has not helped.
- Paired the remote using Bootcamp manager in Windows - did not help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This probably has something to do with the wake from sleep features in windows. A number of things must be on and working in order to get an input device to wake up your machine.

Here are some resources:

Microsoft FAQ on sleep:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Sleep-and-hibernation-frequently-asked-questions

Vista power troubleshooting (still applicable for win7):
http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/vista/vista_hibernate.htm

Microsoft Troubleshooting KB: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907477

On top of that, here are some things to check/doublecheck (I expect you already did some of these).

1. Does the BIOS have any features to control wake from sleep?
2. Is the device listed when you run the following command: **powercfg -devicequery wake_from_any**
3. When you right click on the device in Device manager and go to properties. Is there a power management tab?
4. What happens when you plug in a keyboard or mouse. Can those devices wake up the system?

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your 3rd point led me to the solution. There are 2 items named `HID-compliant consumer control device` under `Human Interface Devices` in the Device Manager. I right-clicked on them and ticked the checkbox `Allow this device to wake the computer` on the Power management tab. And that did it - no more getting up from the sofa to start the machine :P Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

According to this [thread](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2323354&tstart=205), for the remote to wake up Windows 7, the service [Human Interface Device Access](http://www.blackviper.com/wiki/Human_Interface_Device_Access) must be running.

By default this service is defined as "Manual", since most hardware comes with its own software drivers to use the functionality this service provides.

You may try to start it up from the Services applet, to verify if it makes a difference. If it works, you may setup this service as "Automatic" to always start up with the computer.

Comment: Thanks, tried the suggestion but no luck. I've updated my question as well